# get aws cli 'multipart_chunksize' value using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, aws-cli

I am developing an application in python and I need to calculate the number of `S3 Puts`, for this I require the total size of file to be divided with `multipart_chunksize` to find total number of chunks.

I can get the `multipart_chunksize` value using this shell command

```
aws configure get default.s3.multipart_chunksize
```

I can call this command in python using some standard library (`subprocess` etc.), but I would really like to avoid that.

Is there is a way to get the `multipart_chunksize` value using a python library like `boto`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there isn't currently an easy way to get this in `boto3`. It gets set as a default parameter for the `TransferConfig` class, but you would have to do introspection to query that in code. I doubt it will ever be changed from 8MB, so you could make that assumption for now.

> https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/s3/transfer.py#L242

```py
KB = 1024
MB = KB * KB
class TransferConfig(S3TransferConfig):
    def __init__(multipart_chunksize=8*MB)
```

It looks like you want to use the CLI configuration from within boto3, but boto3 does **not** pull from that. If you want to manage that configuration you'll have to create  your own `TransferConfig` object and pass it through. Then you would always know the chunk size.

Comment: @Jordan- Thanks for the information. I have one more doubt regarding the chunk size. 8MB should be transformed as 8*1024*1024 Bytes or 8*1000*1000 Bytes?